# how to solve manifest merger file in android studio 3.4 above version?

Tags: android, file, android-studio, manifest

Execution failed for task `:app:processDebugManifest`

Manifest merger failed:

> uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 1 cannot be smaller than version 7 declared in library [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0] C:\Users\bsuni\AndroidStudioProjects\Rec\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.2.0\AndroidManifest.xml Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v7.appcompat" to force usage

Comment: show your build.gradle file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update the minimum SDK 7 to 16. And also update the Max version to the latest. Always try to use the latest version and latest build version. Please try this build configuration:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.XXX.XXXX"  // your application package 
    multiDexEnabled true
    minSdkVersion 16  // here 16 so change accordingly 
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.0"
}
```

And also update the all support version from 23.2.0 to 28.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

looks like you need to increase the minDK version to 7 in your app gradle file

Answer (score 1):

```
 <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v7.appcompat"/>
```

don't forget to include xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" too, before the  tag

Answer (score 0):

Some issue with minSdkVersion so correct it, change it more than 7

```
 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.XXX.XXXX"  // your application package 
    multiDexEnabled true
    minSdkVersion 14  // here 14 so change accordingly 
    targetSdkVersion 18
    versionCode 99
    versionName "11.1.5.5"
}
```

Another way
First try above and not works than make following changes

```
<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v7.appcompat"/>
```

to your AndroidManifest.xml and it will work. This will enable the Manifest merger to add this also when the API version is older. Don't forget to add the tools namespace at your xml root as shown below.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.app"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
```